# Allow admin to access all mappings Spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot rest controller with mappings: 
mapping1
 `@GetMapping(value = "/onlyUser1Access")`
and mapping2 
`@GetMapping(value = "/onlyUser2Access")`

Assigned roles are user1 = ROLE_USER1, user2 = ROLE_USER2

I want to allow admin to access both mappings (there are other mappings besides mapping1 and mapping2 which admin can access).

I could only achieve: 
- mapping1 can be accessed by user1, not by admin.
- mapping2 can be accessed by user2, not by admin.

I want admin to access all mappings.

Following is my code in configure(HttpSecurity http) method:

````
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/onlyUser1Access").hasRole("USER1")
                .antMatchers("/onlyUser2Access").hasRole("USER2")
                .antMatchers("/", "/**").hasRole("ADMIN")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing  `.antMatchers("/onlyUser1Access/**").hasAnyRole("USER1", "ADMIN")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Small correction to your answer. The method is `hasAnyRole(String... roles)` instead of hasRoles() and `antMatcher("/onlyUser1Access")`. Thanks a million.

Comment: you can still use this `.antMatchers("/onlyUser1Access/**")` in case you'll have sub-urls under "/onlyUser1Access"